# How to show desired number of elements in list according to if else condition?

Tags: jquery, list

I want to show only desired number of elements in list when I click  on button (say 3 number of itesm will be shown according to input condition)  How would I accomplish it?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var list = $('#myList li:gt(0)');
    list.hide();
    $('a#myList-toggle').click(function () {
        var username = $("#<%= uname.ClientID %>").val();
        var pwd = $("#<%= pwd.ClientID %>").val();
        var ints = $("#<%= uname.ClientID %>").val();
        var list1 = $('#myList li:gt(3)');
        alert(username);
        list.slideToggle(400);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

<a href="#" id="myList-toggle">Show the rest</a>

UserName: 
<asp:TextBox id="uname" Text="" runat="server" />
PassWord : <asp:TextBox id="pwd" Text="" runat="server"/>

<ul id="myList" style="margin-bottom: 0px" >
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>



</ul>

<asp:Button  id="Login" Text="Login" runat="server" />



</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jquery slice function.function prototype is like so:

```
$(someselector).slice(start [, end]);
```

it selects top m-n starting from n.note that indices are zero based.for example :

```
  <ul>
     <li>list item 1</li>
     <li>list item 2</li>
     <li>list item 3</li>
     <li>list item 4</li>
     <li>list item 5</li>
   </ul>

$('li').slice(2, 4).css('background-color', 'red');
```

will be applied to items [3,4]

hope this help.